# How to filter repeated rows and sort data without including the ORDER BY fields on the SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following store procedure declared on SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ContratoMarcoGP_FuerzaTrabajo]
@IdContratoMarco    INT = NULL,
@Desde              DATETIME,
@Hasta              DATETIME,
@IdSede             INT,
@IdIdioma           INT,
@IdProveedor        INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
            CAST(PD.[IdPeriodoDetalle] AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(E.[IdEspecialidad] AS VARCHAR) AS [IdUnico], -- generado para el storetable
            PD.[IdPeriodoDetalle],
            M.[Descripcion] + ' - ' + CAST(PD.[Anio] AS CHAR(4)) AS [PeriodoDetalle], 
            E.[IdEspecialidad], 
            E.[Descripcion] AS [Especialidad], 
            CAST(
                (CASE 
                    WHEN CMH.[Horas] IS NULL THEN 0
                    ELSE CMH.[Horas]
                END) 
            AS INT)AS [Horas]
        FROM 
            [PeriodoDetalle] PD 
            INNER JOIN ProveedorPersona PP ON PP.IdProveedor = @IdProveedor
            INNER JOIN [Especialidad] E ON E.IdEspecialidad = PP.IdEspecialidad
            LEFT JOIN [ContratoMarcoHoras] CMH ON E.[IdEspecialidad] = CMH.[IdEspecialidad] AND PD.[IdPeriodoDetalle] = CMH.[IdPeriodoDetalle] AND CMH.[IdContratoMarco] = @IdContratoMarco -- traigo las horas cargadas sólo para el contrato indicado.
            INNER JOIN [Mes] M ON PD.[Mes] = M.[IdMes] AND M.[IdIdioma] = @IdIdioma
        WHERE 
        (   
            [FechaDesdeGP] BETWEEN @Desde AND @Hasta
        OR  
            [FechaHastaGP] BETWEEN @Desde AND @Hasta
        OR
            (
                @Desde BETWEEN [FechaDesdeGP] AND [FechaHastaGP]
            OR
                @Hasta BETWEEN [FechaDesdeGP] AND [FechaHastaGP]
            )
        )
        AND
            PD.[IdSede] = @IdSede
        AND
            E.[IdIdioma] = @IdIdioma
        AND 
            PP.IdProveedor = @IdProveedor   
        ORDER BY 
            PD.[Anio], PD.[Mes]
END
```

The problem is that when I call this procedure with a few parameters,it returns some repeated rows, so I thought to use the DISTINCT keywork, but it tells me that I need to include in the SELECT the fields that are specified in the ORDER BY, and I don't want it to. I mean, I need to include only the fields which I had specified in the SELECT clause because it returns this data on a C# DataTable. 
How can I sort this data by this fields and filter the repeated rows without including new fields in the SELECT? Is possibly to use a subquery for filter the required fields in two steps?

Comment: remove the ORDER BY and do it in C# on the DataTable?

Comment: Here are two easy brute force answers... 1) get rid of the order by and order it in your c# code.  2) add the columns and then wrap the whole thing in a subselect.  But, you are better off going w/ Gordon's answer. :)

Comment: Thanks Tanner, it could be another good way to do it. I thought to do it this way, but i prefer to have the whole logic in the database.

Comment: Those columns not currently in the `SELECT` but present in the `ORDER BY` - they may contain multiple, **different** values, for rows which do match on all columns in the `SELECT` clause. The `DISTINCT` will reduce these to a single row - how is the server meant to know *what* value to use for those columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `distinct`, use `group by` and then include aggregation functions in the `order by`.  Here is a template based on your query:

```
select CAST(PD.[IdPeriodoDetalle] AS VARCHAR(255)) + '-' + CAST(E.[IdEspecialidad] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS [IdUnico],
       . . .
from [PeriodoDetalle] PD 
     . . .
where . . .
group by <all the columns in the select>
order by max(PD.[Anio]), max(PD.[Mes]);
```

Note that I added in length arguments for `varchar()`.  In SQL Server, you should always include the length of the field.  The default varies depending on the context, and relying on the default can create difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon!! It solves my problem in a really efficient way. It was a really good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite understand the question, but at least a part of it:

"but it tells me that I need to include in the SELECT the fields that are specified in the ORDER BY, and I don't want it to."

Maybe an temporary table?

For example: if you want this:

```
select distinct date,value from dbo.TAB_A2
order by id
```

That would give an error. Instead:

```
create table #tab_a3(id int, date datetime,value int)

insert into #tab_A3
    select distinct id, date,value 
    from dbo.TAB_A2
    order by id

select date,value from #tab_A3
```

Comment: The answer of Gordon solves my question. In that line I meant that "you need to write on your SELECT whatever the fields you set on you ORDER BY clause if you use the DISTINCT keyword". Thanks anyway! I could help someone else maybe :)

Comment: I was busy testing this while Gordon wrote his answer, should have F5'ed :P For that specific line you wrote, this solves that as , in my example, id won't get into the final result. Anyway, good to see you've got your answer:)